# "File Save Failed" error when working with Crystal Reports in VS2008

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

Occasionally while attempting to save a Crystal Report that I'm working on in VS2008, a dialog titled "File Save Failed" pops up saying "The document could not be saved in C:\Users\Phillip\AppData\Local\Temp{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}.rpt. It has been saved in  C:\Users\Phillip\AppData\Local\Temp\~zzz{YYYYYYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYYYYYYYYYY}.tmp."

If I OK the dialog, I get a "Save File As" dialog. If I specify the correct location of the report file, I'm asked if I want to replace the existing file. If I say "Yes", I get an error message saying "The operation could not be completed. The system cannot find the file specified." Even if I specify a completely different filename, in a different folder (e.g. C:/test.rpt) I get the same "operation could not be completed" error.

Sometimes if I wait a moment, then try to save again, it works fine. More frequently, however, I keep getting the "Save File As" dialog. My only option then is to close the report and discard my changes.

This is an intermittent problem - much of the time, saving the report works just fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copernic Desktop Search sometimes locks files so that they can't be written. Closing the program resolves the problem. Perhaps the same problem occurs with other search engines too.

Comment: Took me a while, but I've just been able to confirm that this is exactly what was causing my problem. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem VS2010 and Crystal which may be related

Suddenly saving was not working (asterisk never went away) - then VS would crash on trying to exit the report form (presumably trying to save).

I found that by changing the tab to preview the report (at the bottom) which I rarely do due to the fact that it is rarely accurate enough - I could save from there.

Saving during the preview removed the (dirty) astersisk in the top tab and allowed me to exit the form cleanly.

Too early to tell if the report is still ok - I too have had to recreate reports in the past.

Though once I did download the demo for the full Crystal which allowed me to mend a report so that is sometimes worth it too.

Comment: Further to the above I just found that by unchecking the "Save data in the report option" (top left of the Main Report Preview pane) it allows my report to save without crashing Visual Studio from the main report tab.  Hope that helps others.

Comment: Thanks Tim, You saved my life , I was wondering search engines to search engine.. and was just going to scratch all my hairs. I owe you a beer. Thanks a lot. :).  "Save data in the report option"  almost made me behave like Zombie..

Answer (score 0):

sounds like a job for process moniter. you should be able use process moniter to see what's really hapening and why.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx

Or you could install VS2008 sp1 and cross your fingers. (I'd do both)