# while saving crystal report after editing getting error

Tags: vb.net

while saving crystal report am getting error like this:

[image]

after editing my crystal report i try to save my crystal report.
that time i getting error like this:
after closing visual studio..am not getting this error..
so every time i have to close and open visual studio..
why this error is coming .if i edit small field in 
my crystal report then also i am getting error like this

any one know how to fix this issue..please help me..

Answer (score 0):

looks like its been already answered, please check below link.

[Crystal report save error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30995/file-save-failed-error-when-working-with-crystal-reports-in-vs2008?rq=1)

Comment: in this link not having proper solution for resolving this issue

Comment: i think its because of the 3rd party sofware "Copernic desktop search" , do you have this software installed in your PC?

Comment: no sir..i not installed copernic desktop search.i am working on windows 8